# OnClick of My Location marker in Google Maps Display two Icons at bottom of screen

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers

In `Google Maps` I'm fetching the user location and displaying the custom marker icon for user's current location. Everything is fine. But when I click on the marker icon there are two small icons at the bottom of the screen appears.

One is `Google Maps` `Navigation` icon and another one is `Google Maps` icon. On click of these icons its taking me to `Google Maps` app.

Again on click of maps they disappears. So this keeps on happening if I click on user location marker. For reference I'm adding code and screenshots.

```
public void getMyLocation(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE);
    CameraPosition.Builder builder = new CameraPosition.Builder();
    builder.zoom(15).target(latLng);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
         .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_place_blue_24dp))
         .position(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(builder.build()));
}
```

[image: Before clicking on location marker]

[image: After on click of marker]

I have no clue why this is happening! Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature of the new version of Play Services.
You can disable it from GoogleMap's UiSettings.

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This helped me... Thanks :)